# Formatting the date and time using angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

I have a date format in the following way,

```
"tranDate": "2015-11-02T18:30:00.000Z"
```

how do i format the date and time in human readable way.

```
date: 2015-11-02
time: 18:30:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the [date filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) will handle the UTC datetime string as it is.

Answer (score 1):

Since your string contains Zulu time, first convert the string to a date using `new Date` as follows:

```
$scope.date = new Date(obj['tranDate'].replace(' ', 'T'))
```

Then use angular's inbuilt [date filters.](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date) in the template. Example:

```
{{date | date: 'd MMM yyyy'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

**IN CONCROLLER**

put the following code in controller

```
$scope.date_test = {"tranDate": new Date()}
```

**IN HTML**

```
date : {{date_test.tranDate  | date: 'yyyy-M-dd'}}
time : {{date_test.tranDate  | date:"h:mm:ss"}}
```

This is an exmaple of formating the date and time

http://plnkr.co/edit/nYChVvYOmok4jX16CNae?p=preview